# 16.04, wifi stopped working after dist-upgrade

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, upgrade, atheros

I updated today using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to the newest kernel and now ubuntu won't load the driver for my atheros AR93xx wireless adapter. running `lshw -C network` shows that the device is unclaimed and when i try to run `sudo modprobe -v ath9k`, it tells me the key was rejected by service. Trying to use the -f flag, it says exec firnat error. I already tried to reinstall the kernel and that didn't fix it. Not sure where to go from here.

result of modinfo ath9k:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     1B84AD8C53440158CD581F2
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001028sd0000020Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001043sd000085F2bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000017AAsd00004026bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000017AAsd00003026bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E099bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E091bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E081bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E08Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E07Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd0000A120bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd000028A4bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd000028A2bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002813bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002810bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Fsd00007202bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002F82bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000218Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000218Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002182bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000213Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002130bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000813bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000803bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000692bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00001832bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000832bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000612bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000652bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000642bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd0000302Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000412Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd00004129bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001028sd0000020Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000103Csd00002005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000103Csd0000217Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000103Csd000018E3bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000213Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000213Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000682bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd000006A2bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000662bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000672bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000622bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd00003028bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E069bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd0000302Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003026bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002F8Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000218Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd000028A3bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd000028A1bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002812bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002811bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00006671bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00001842bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000842bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd000006B2bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000632bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd0000A119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E068bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002176bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003028bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000037sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv00001A56sd00002003bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000010CFsd00001783bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000014CDsd00000064bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000014CDsd00000063bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv0000103Csd00001864bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006641bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006631bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001043sd0000850Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001A3Bsd00002110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001969sd00000091bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000017AAsd00003214bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv0000168Csd00003117bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006661bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001A3Bsd00002116bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000033sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001043sd0000850Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00001C01bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00001C00bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001F95bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001195bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001F86bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001186bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00002001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00002000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Fsd00007197bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E04Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E04Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000011ADsd00006628bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000011ADsd00006627bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001C56sd00004001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002100bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002C97bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000017AAsd00003219bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000017AAsd00003218bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C708bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C680bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C706bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd00004106bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd00004105bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000185Fsd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000185Fsd00003119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000168Csd00003122bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000168Csd00003119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E075bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002152bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd0000126Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002126bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001237bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002086bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv00001A56sd00002001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv00001A56sd00002000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv00001A3Bsd00002C37bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd00001536bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd0000147Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd0000147Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv0000185Fsd0000309Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv00001A32sd00000306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000011ADsd00006642bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000011ADsd00006632bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv0000105Bsd0000E01Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv00001A3Bsd00001C71bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000029sv0000168Csd00002096bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000029sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000027sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000024sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000023sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          platform:qca956x_wmac
alias:          platform:qca953x_wmac
alias:          platform:qca955x_wmac
alias:          platform:ar934x_wmac
alias:          platform:ar933x_wmac
alias:          platform:ath9k
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-62-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           led_active_high:Invert LED polarity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)
```

Comment: Try this [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers)

Comment: Is `secure boot` disabled in your BIOS?

Comment: Can you edit the question to add results for `modinfo ath9k`

Comment: Secure boot is disabled

Comment: Did you update your kernel to something other than the version supplied with your Ubuntu distribution? What version are you running? If so... 1) we don't support that here, 2) downgrade to the current kernel for your dist and see if the wireless works again.

Comment: I used the default repository and updated to 4.4.0-61-generic. when I use the 4.4.0-59-generic kernel, the wireless works again.